# Call Django API internally using relative URL path and request body

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm migrating to GKE from GAE. Due to a number of reasons, I've to switch from Cloud Tasks to Cloud Pub/Sub. Using supervisord, I've set up a service that listens to newly published messages. The messages contain HTTP method, relative URL and payload.

Using the following code, I'm able to get a `ResolverMatch` object for the relative URL:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve  # django.urls for Django>=2.0

task = {
    'http_method': 'PUT',
    'relative_uri': '/accounts/1/',
    'body': '{"name": "John Doe"}',
    'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
}
match = resolve(task['relative_uri'])
print(match.func, match.kwargs)
```

Unfortunately, I'm using both ViewSets and individual methods for defining routes. So I can't just invoke the `create` method for a viewset if the HTTP method is POST, as it might not exist.

Is there a way to call an API in the same Django app internally using just relative URL path, HTTP method and request body?

Comment: Is the server actually running locally on a port you can access, or is this just a "run the code with simulated request"?

Comment: There's no port I can access. I'd like to run the code with simulated request